# Access child class Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, qt

I have a sub-classed `QTreeView` which is acting as a generic property editor for objects in a 3D scene. All objects inherit from a base class called transform which has information about position, rotation etc.

At the moment when I add objects to the tree view, the base class properties appear and work fine. However, I would like to be able to access properties i declare in the child class as well. What is the best way to do this? I have thus far been unsuccessful by simply using the `Q_PROPERTY` macro in the child class.

Comment: Why did you sub-classed it `QTreeView`? There is no point for doing it. You should provide some `QAbstractItemModel` (probably subclass of `QAbstractTableModel` or `QAbstractListModel`).

Comment: have you tried casting?